# Separate .so libraries from .apk

Tags: android, arcgis

I have an enterprise app which I am deploying manually (no Google Play) which uses a number of .so libraries for mapping (ArcGIS). However, the .so files (arm, armv7a, x86) in the libs folder blow the .apk size out from 3mb to 21mb. I dont particularly want to remove one of the .so files (removing support for that architecture), or mess around with one .apk per architecture.

Can anyone think of a way I can update my app without including the .so files in each update .apk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have the Java portion of your app manually download the appropriate .so files into your app's internal storage folder and mark them executable.

You will then have to load them with System.load() and the full pathname of the .so file, rather than System.loadLibrary() and the trimmed library name.

The biggest issue here is that you are now responsible for matching the ABI's yourself, and more importantly, providing your own protection against being tricked into installing a modified or imposter library which might do something nefarious in the name of your app and using it's permissions.

Of course you have to make sure not to try to call any of the native methods before you have installed them.

You could also consider delivering the .so files as binary assets each in its own skeleton .apk having a shared user id (and matching certificate) as your main .apk

Or you could simply make platform-specific .apk's for each target, containing only one .so, and have your distribution system pick the right ones (though that doesn't help with the upgrade problem).

Comment: Thanks, will have a go at that

Comment: Had a go at your first method (keeping the .so separate and load using System.load()). Unfortunately, ArcGIS does the library load internally, so even if I load the lib manually, I still crash and burn when ArcGIS then tries to load the .so iteslf. Tried copying the .so to the app/devices lib folder, but no cigar (read only)

Comment: You could make a tiny dummy one (in each ABI) for it to load, or you could try to catch the failure (actually surprised it is fatal - it normally is not) or you could modify the form of this library you do have, even if it is not source.